# Simple bike tire PSI web app - Why isn't HTML being updated with the message from the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to input some information in the form, then get a recommendation of the correct PSI to fill their bike tire. I can't get the HTML to update from the JS code. I'm a beginner, so I'm probably missing something obvious... Why doesn't "document.getElementById("psi").innerHTML = message;" give me what I'm looking for?

```js
var riderweight, bikeweight, tubeless, tirewidth ;

function psi() {

    riderweight = document.getElementById('riderweight').value;
    bikeweight = document.getElementById('bikeweight').value;
    tubeless = document.getElementById('tubeless').value;
    tirewidth = document.getElementById('tirewidth').value;

    var totalweight = riderweight + bikeweight;
    var baseline = 100;
    var psi = 0;

    // Shorten this code...
    if (tirewidth == 23) {
        if (totalweight < 180) {
            psi = baseline - 5;
        } else if (totalweight > 200) {
            psi = baseline + 5;
        } else {
            psi = baseline;
        }
        if (tubeless == Yes) {
            psi -= 10;
        }
    }
    // TO-DO
    else if (tirewidth == 25) {
        psi = baseline - 15;
    } else if (tirewidth == 28) {
        psi = baseline - 30;
    } else if (tirewidth == 30) {
        psi = baseline - 35;
    } else if (tirewidth == 32) {
        psi = baseline - 35;
    }

    message = "Your recommended PSI is " + psi;
    document.getElementById("psi").innerHTML = message;

    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1>Bike Tire PSI Calculator</h1>
        <h5>*Only for 700cc road bike tires</h5> <br>

        <form id="psi-form">
            <h3>Input rider weight:</h3>
                <input name="riderweight" id="riderweight" type="number" min="80" max="300" default="150" placeholder="Rider lbs">
            <br>

            <h3>Input bike weight:</h3>
                <input name="bikeweight" id="bikeweight" type="number" min="0" max="50" default="15" placeholder="Bike lbs">
            <br>

            <h3>Tire width in cc?</h3>
                <select id="tirewidth">
                    <option id="23" type="number">23</option>
                    <option id="25" type="number">25</option>
                    <option id="28" type="number">28</option>
                    <option id="30" type="number">30</option>
                    <option id="32" type="number">32</option>
                </select>
            <br>

            <h3>Using tubeless tires?</h3>
                <select id="tubeless">
                    <option id="yes" value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
                    <option id="no" value="false">No</option>
                </select>
            <br>

            <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="psi()">Get suggested PSI</button>
        </form>
        
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="psi">
        PSI recommendation will go here <!-- return PSI here-->
    </div>

    <script src="psi.js"></script>
```

Comment: `"ReferenceError: Yes is not defined"`

Comment: Use Javascript console (F12 in some browsers) to see the errors in your scripts. In this case you should replace `if (tubeless == Yes) {` with `if (tubeless === true) {` which is the same as just `if (tubeless) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (tirewidth == 23) {
        if (totalweight < 180) {
            psi = baseline - 5;
        } else if (totalweight > 200) {
            psi = baseline + 5;
        } else {
            psi = baseline;
        }
        if (tubeless == Yes) {
            psi -= 10;
        }
    }
```

You got an error in the last if block, maybe you want the string of 'Yes', not Yes variable